# perl date calculation with dates of the format 2012-02-03 00:00:00

Tags: perl, date

I need some help with date calculations in perl with dates for the format "2012-02-03 00:00:00". In particular is there a tool I could use to just increment the days and it switches to month and year correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

See [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $ts = '2012-02-03 00:00:00';
my ($y, $m, $d) = ($ts =~ /([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/);
my $dt = DateTime->new(year => $y, month => $m, day => $d);
$dt->add( months => 2, days => 3 );

print $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "\n";
```

---

It's actually a little cleaner to use a DateTime::Format class, and you get error checking for free.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $ts = '2012-02-03 00:00:00';
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($ts);
$dt->add( months => 2, days => 3 );
print $format->format_datetime($dt), "\n";
```

Comment: You can also look at https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime::Format::MySQL to pare the code down just a little bit more.

Comment: Rather than be stuck with various specific formats, I'd just go with [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/)

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I added Strptime example. I fixed the output of your original code as well; it had an undesired "T" between the date and time.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you. That's much better.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module is a standard part of the Perl installation and probably does all that you need.

This program uses your example date and adds two months and three days, then a further 400 days. Two alternative ways of displaying the values are shown

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime('2012-02-03 00:00:00', $format);
$dt = $dt->add_months(2);
$dt += 3 * ONE_DAY;

print $dt->strftime($format), "\n";

$dt += 400 * ONE_DAY;

printf "%s %s\n", $dt->ymd, $dt->hms;
```

**output**

```
2012-04-06 00:00:00
2013-05-11 00:00:00
```

Comment: That can't possibly be correct, since the number of seconds in a day isn't constant.

Comment: @ikegami It's "usually" constant :-) When using Time::Piece and adding/subtracting days starting with time truncated to the day, I'll usually add an extra half-day when adding, or subtract a half-day less when subtracting, and truncate the result to the day.

Answer (score 1):

This is all perfectly possible within core using the `POSIX` time-handling functions.

The standard `POSIX::mktime` function already copes with denormalised values, and can correct for days/months out of range. Additionally, `POSIX::strftime` actually calls this on the given values before formatting them, so it will adjust correctly.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime mktime );
use POSIX::strptime qw( strptime );

my $format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

my @t = strptime( "2012-02-03 00:00:00", $format );
@t = @t[0..5]; # Throw away wday and yday

$t[3] += 3; # mday
$t[4] += 2; # mon

say strftime $format, @t;

$t[3] += 400; # mday

say strftime $format, @t;
```

Gives

```
2012-04-06 00:00:00
2013-05-11 00:00:00
```